# Retrieve code between two tags

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi guys i'm trying to retrieve the link between this two tag eg  text here it will then store it in a list, how do i retrieve those text with the pattern and matcher

```
public void getlinks() {
    Pattern Start = Pattern.compile(this.PatternStart);  //<Link>
    Pattern End = Pattern.compile(this.PatternEnd);      //</Link>
    Matcher mStart = Start.matcher(this.Source); // matches Start
    Matcher mEnd = End.matcher(this.Source); // matches end

   ????????????
}
```

Trying to find the link between  and  inside a html source, just using  as an example

Comment: Show us what the text looks like and say exactly what you are trying to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you do like this:

```
public static List<String> getLinks(String text) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<tagstart>(.*?)<tagend>").matcher(text);
    List<String> linkList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        linkList.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return linkList;
}
```

where `<tagstart>` and `<tagend>` are your starting and ending tags. The `matcher.group(1)` gives you everything between the tags, where `matcher.group()` or `matcher.group(0)` would give you the tags too.
Note that it is important to use the `(.*?)` if you have a text with multiple tag pairs, otherwise this will match the first `<tagstart>` and the last `<tagend>` and return everything in between.
An example usage would be:

```
    System.out.println(getLinks("<tagstart>beer<tagend><tagstart>juice<tagend>"));
```

which prints

```
[beer, juice]
```

Comment: matcher(text) what id i need a stringbuilder inside instead of just a normal text?

Comment: Do you want to return a list of `StringBuilder`, or do you want to pass a `StringBuilder` as the argument to `getLinks()`?

Comment: i would like to pass a stringbuilder to getlinks but return a list of extracted links

Comment: `StringBuilder` has a `toString()` method, so you can easily convert it.

Comment: public void getLinks(String text) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<cite>(.*?)</cite>").matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        listOfLinks.add(matcher.group(1));
}
   }

What about this? I used a variable outside the method

Comment: Sure, if that suits the rest of the class better, that works too.